# How to set connection variable with specific file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is possible to set variable for `host`, `dbname`, `username`, and `password` using specific file in codeigniter? If possible, how to set variable connection in specific file also can be read in `config/database.php`? We know that CI using `config/database.php` to configure a connection.

**EDITED**

This is the code:

**rootweb/index.php**

```
$this->config->load('config', TRUE);
```

**rootweb/config.php**

```
$config['host']="localhost";
$config['dbname']="mydb";
$config['username']="myusername";
$config['password']="mypass";
```

I also try using this :

```
$config['dsn']="postgre://myusername:mypass@localhost/mydb?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci&cache_on=true&cachedir=/path/to/cache";
```

**application/config/config.php**

```
include ('config.php');
```

**application/config/database.php**

```
$host = $this->config->item('host', 'config');
$dbname = $this->config->item('dbname', 'config');
$username = $this->config->item('username', 'config');
$password = $this->config->item('password', 'config');
$dsn = $this->config->item('dsn', 'config');

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => $dsn,
    'hostname' => $host,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'database' => $dbname,
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    ...
);
```

And still showing blank page.

Comment: post what you have done so far

Comment: what are you doing? Read carefully  codeigniter manual. How to create config and where to create config file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can set database connection in specific file like this:

```
$dsn = 'dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci&cache_on=true&cachedir=/path/to/cache';
$this->load->database($dsn);
```

Example for localhost:

```
$dsn = 'mysqli://root:@localhost/test?char_set=utf8&dbcollat=utf8_general_ci&cache_on=false&cachedir='; //If do not want cache
$this->load->database($dsn);
```

Refer this codeigniter documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html).

Comment: thanks for help. Let's say that I set some variables to `globalconfig.php`. Then easily attach it with `require 'globalconfig.php'` at index.php but only show blank page.

Comment: You have to  put `globalconfig.php`  and Call config file in codeigniter like this: `$this->config->load('globalconfig', TRUE);`

`$host = $this->config->item('host', 'globalconfig');`

Comment: I have edited my question, Try to follow your suggest. Please look again.